# Issue detecting running processes from shell script

Tags: grep, ps, echo, sendmail, mailx

Script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
kafka=`ps -ef | grep 'kafka' | grep -v grep | wc -l`
echo $kafka
if [ $kafka<3 ]
then
echo "Hi Support Team,

Kafka is down on QA/Dev server $hostname .Please take immediate action

Regards,
Application Support Team"| mailx -s "Kafka down on QA/Dev server" abc@.com
fi
```

Output:

```
-bash-4.2$ ./mail.sh
2
./mail.sh: line 4: 3: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/). There are 2 errors in that line. "*< is for string comparisons. Use -lt instead.*" and "*You are missing a required space here.*". (And many more hints for most other lines)

Comment: @pLumo Interestingly enough, shellcheck is wrong about the `<`.

Answer (score 4):

The unquoted `<` operator is a redirection operator in the shell.  The error indicates that the shell tries to redirect from a file called `3`. You most likely wanted to use `-lt` to compare two integers.

Here's an alternative implementation:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

if ! pkill -0 kafka; then
    mail -s 'Kafka down on QA/Dev server' abc@.com <<END
Hi Support Team,

Kafka is down on QA/Dev server $hostname.
Please take immediate action

Regards,
Application Support Team
END
fi
```

The above script will use `pkill` to send the "zero signal" to each `kafka` process (use `pkill -0 -f kafka` to search for the substring `kafka` in the whole command line, not just the command name).  If no such process exists, this will cause `pkill` to exit with a non-zero exit-status, triggering the sending of the email. The "zero signal" is used to test whether a process exists or not, and does not affect the process in any way.

Alternatively, if you want to count the number of `kafka` processes and trigger the email for less than three:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$( pgrep kafka | wc -l )" -lt 3 ]; then
    mail -s 'Kafka down on QA/Dev server' abc@.com <<END
Hi Support Team,

Kafka is down on QA/Dev server $hostname.
Please take immediate action

Regards,
Application Support Team
END
fi
```

The `pgrep` call outputs the process IDs for all process names matching the given pattern, one per line. Use `pgrep -f kafka` to search for the substring `kafka` in the whole command line, not just the command name.

Both of the scripts above assume that the variable `hostname` has been set and exported outside of the script.  You could use `$(hostname)` in place of `$hostname` to call the `hostname` utility in the here-document.

Comment: `pgrep -f pattern` is analagous to `ps -ef | grep pattern`

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, thanks, added notes about this.