# "ps -ef" command issue while executed the from script and direct execution

Tags: grep, ps

If I execute this command alone separately I am getting 3 which is actually correct:

```
ps -ef | grep kafka | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

But when placed inside the script I am getting it as 5:

```
[mradmin@orionkafka-dt-t1 scripts]$ ./kafkamonitoring.sh
5
```

The script is

```sh
if [[ $( ps -ef | grep kafka | grep -v grep | wc -l) -lt 3 ]]
then
echo $(ps -ef | grep kafka | grep -v grep | wc -l)
mail -s 'Kafka down on trn environment' abc@abc.com <<END
Hi Support Team,

Kafka is down on trn server $(hostname) .Please take immediate action

Regards,
Application Support Team
END
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is called `kafkamonitoring.sh`, which includes the string `kafka`.  The name of the script will appear in the `ps` output. This accounts for one of the extra matches.

The fact that you're running the `ps` command in a command substitution will make another instance of the script's name occur in the `ps` output.  That accounts for the other extra match.

You will be better served by using `pkill` and/or `pgrep` as mentioned in my answer to your previous question (from which you have incorporated much material already): [Issue detecting running processes from shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650012/issue-detecting-running-processes-from-shell-script)  For example, if the process is called exactly `kafka`, then `pgrep -x kafka` will match that command exactly.  You may also specify a specific user with `-u`.